# kali linux no wifi networks pop up. vmware

Tags: kali-linux, networksetup

[image]

I'm using vm ware and my wired connecting works but by my wireless wifi connecting there don't show a network up.
Operating system : windows 10, virtualization : vmware workstation pro 15.

Comment: Vmware is passing an internet connection to your virtual machine via a virtual NIC. This virtual NIC is going to be translated in most virtual machines as a wired connection. You will need a wireless usb adapter to pass through to the VM, or do PCI pass through of your internal wireless card if possible. Note that with the second option your host will not be able to use the wireless card when set up like this. Please update your post with additional context, such as your host Operating System, wireless chipset, and virtualization software. Thank you.

Comment: operating system : windows 10, virtualization : vmware workstation pro 15

Comment: You are likely going to need to get your hands on a USB WiFi adapter that is compatible with Kali Linux or run Kali as a Live Boot to complete the task at hand.

Answer (score 0):

VMware does **NOT** pass the physical adapters on your machine - wifi included - for networking through to your VMs.  This is because the network 'hardware' shown to the guest is 'virtual' and not the actual equipment on the system itself.  This concept applies to VMware Workstaion, VMware ESXi, VirtualBox, etc.

You will need to get your hands on a USB WiFi adapter that works with Kali and set up USB Passthrough for that device so you can dedicate it to the VM for usage.

Alternatively, use the Kali Live Boot mechanism to boot your computer into Kali directly.  This will bypass the VM requirement and just work off your computer directly, though you won't be able to use your 'native' OS on the computer during this method.

Beyond these two mechanisms (one with an extra piece of hardware, and one booting up the entire computer into Kali directly), there is no way to get Wireless Networks visible within the Kali VM.

Comment: If I boot my computer can I than go easely back to my windows or delete kali linux than my windows? sorry i'm new in kali linux and I don't wanna fuck up my pc. And what is a good wifi adapter for kali linux? Thnx.

Comment: @kippezijngeil if you are unfamiliar with how live booting works then I would say if you want to learn about Linux use something more beginner friendly such as Ubuntu or Linux Mint. If you want to learn about penetration testing 24 out of 25 of the top tools listed by [sectools.org](https://sectools.org/) are available on Windows as well as Linux.

Comment: @kippezijngeil If you boot into the Kali USB in "Live" mode and *don't* install Kali to the hard drive, then all you have to do is reboot without the USB stick inserted to get back to Windows, yes.

Comment: But I do agree with kemotep here, you should really be using a beginner-friendly OS, not Kali, to familiarize yourself with the 'basics' of Linux.

Comment: Okay and Ubuntu or Linux Mint is a good begin?